# Change Typescript Function to retrieve JSON data from Session Storage instead of a JSON file

Tags: typescript, observable, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

## Context

I have the following typescript code from [mkdocs-material's bundle.ts](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/blob/f9d5c6709b2692cf083e413c9d944dc9d59b4079/src/assets/javascripts/bundle.ts#L99):

```js
/**
 * Fetch search index
 *
 * @returns Search index observable
 */
function fetchSearchIndex(): Observable<SearchIndex> {
  if (location.protocol === "file:") {
    return watchScript(
      `${new URL("search/search_index.js", config.base)}`
    )
      .pipe(
        // @ts-ignore - @todo fix typings
        map(() => __index),
        shareReplay(1)
      )
  } else {
    return requestJSON<SearchIndex>(
      new URL("search/search_index.json", config.base)
    )
  }
}
```

The `SearchIndex` interface looks like so (located at [src/assets/.../config/index.ts](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/blob/228599b240b0e720ecec008522d18394f6ab82ce/src/assets/javascripts/integrations/search/config/index.ts#L60):

```js
export interface SearchIndex {
  config: SearchConfig
  docs: SearchDocument[]
  options: SearchOptions
}
```

The JSON data in the `search_index.json` has the following structure:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "lang": [
      "en"
    ],
    "separator": "[\\s\\-]+",
    "pipeline": [
      "stopWordFilter"
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "location": "some-location-text",
      "title": "some-title-text",
      "text": "some-text-text"
    },
    {
      "location": "some-location-text",
      "title": "some-title-text",
      "text": "some-text-text"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Question

How can I modify the `fetchSearchIndex()` function so that instead of retrieving/observing the JSON data from the `search_index.json` file, it will retrieve the JSON data from the **session storage** (under the key `search-index`)?

## My Attempt

Do note that I am a Python programmer and not fluent in TypeScript/JavaScript at all. Despite that, here was my attempt:

```js
function getFromSessionStorage(key: string): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable<string>((observer) => {
    try {
      const value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
      if (value === null) {
        observer.error(new Error('Key not found in sessionStorage'));
      } else {
        observer.next(value);
        observer.complete();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      observer.error(error);
    }
  });
}

function fetchSearchIndex(): Observable<SearchIndex> {
  const searchIndex = sessionStorage.getItem('search-index');
  if (searchIndex ) {
    return getFromSessionStorage('search-index')
      .pipe(
        map(x => JSON.parse(x)),
        shareReplay(1)
      )
  } else {
    // original fetchSearchIndex() code here
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, that did not work as I got the following error:

```
index.ts:99 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: r.location.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at ne (index.ts:99:33)
    at new H (index.ts:146:16)
    at index.ts:152:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at s (search.dfff1995.min.js:1:966)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was unrelated to the code that I provided and my code was indeed behaving correctly as it should. The issue was the content of the `search-index` retrieved from the `sessionStorage` was an incorrect JSON.

After fixing the content of the sessionStorage, everything works as it should.